# Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 using Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm getting error when the command trying to run `ionic platform add ios` after `ionic plugin add ../my-custom-plugin`.

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-my-custom-plugin':Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/path/to/myprj/platforms/ios/cordova/node_m
odules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)


Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1
```

My plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/an
droid" id="cordova-plugin-my-custom-plugin" version="0.0.1">
    <name>MyCustomPlugin</name>

    <js-module name="MyCustomPlugin" src="www/Test.js">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugin.mycustomplugin" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="ios">
        <framework src="fmdb" type="podspec" spec="~> 2.6.2" />
        <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
            <feature name="MyCustomPlugin">
                <param name="ios-package" value="MyCustomPlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/ios/MyCustomPlugin.swift" />
    </platform>

</plugin>
```

I already tried to something:

- `pod repo update` ([issue](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-cordova/issues/146))
- `gem install nanoimo` ([issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1584#issuecomment-279690215))
- Reinstall CocoaPods

but still cannot be fixed it. what is wrong?

I'm using:

- macOS Sierra
- ionic 2.2.1
- cordova 6.5.0
- CocoaPods 1.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mistake in podspec name...

Changed `fmdb` to `FMDB` to solved it.

Usually, when you get `Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-my-custom-plugin':Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1`, you can get more information by adding `console.log(capturedOut);` to `node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js` around line 135, at the end of `whenDone` function.

Then remove the plugin (`ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-my-custom-plugin`) and re-add it (`ionic plugin add ../my-custom-plugin`) and you will get additional output that will hint about the issue.

Comment: But I also occurred build error when run `ionic run ios -c -s -device -l`. `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error`...Often cordova is painful...

Comment: I found out the `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error` cause. My project using `cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation` plugin(2.2.5). If we install the plugin then occurred the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This helped us to find the root cause for our problem. In our case the plugin required minimum ios version 9, but project was configured to use 8 :)